# Fragment doesn't change after item click Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment, navigation-drawer

I'm building an app which contains a `NavigationDrawer` to navigate between Fragments.
For some reason, when pressing on any item in the Navigation Drawer the item just marks itself and doesn't change the fragment (tried debug but the item clicks doesn't calls the functions)

The `fragment` is not loading in first click..i have to press twice to reload the `fragment`

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private View navHeader;
private ImageView imgNavHeaderBg, imgProfile;
private TextView txtName, txtCity;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private FloatingActionButton fab;

// urls to load user profile & background
private static final String urlNavHeaderBg = "";
private static final String urlProfileImg = "";

//current menu pressed
public static int navItemIndex = 0;

//tags for fragments
private static final String TAG_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PROFILE = "profile";
private static final String TAG_RATEUS = "rate us";
private static final String TAG_SCORE = "rate score";
private static final String TAG_NOTIFICATIONS = "notifications";
private static final String TAG_SETTINGS = "settings";
public static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;

private String[] activityTitles;
private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
private Handler mHandler;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    //nav view header
    navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtName = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtCity = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.city);
    imgNavHeaderBg = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_header_bg);
    imgProfile = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_profile);

    //load the toolbar titles
    activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Make action here", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    //load the navigator header data
    loadNavHeader();

    //initialize nav menu
    setUpNavigationView();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        navItemIndex = 0;
        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
        loadHomeFragment();
    }
}

private void loadNavHeader() {
    txtName.setText("My Name");
    txtCity.setText("Somewhere, Europe");

    Glide.with(this).load(urlNavHeaderBg).crossFade().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(imgNavHeaderBg);
    Glide.with(this).load(urlProfileImg).thumbnail(0.5f).bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this)).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(imgProfile);

    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(4).setActionView(R.layout.menu_dot);
}

private void loadHomeFragment() {
    selectNavMenu();
    setToolBarTitle();

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        toggleFab();
        return;
    }
    Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    };
    if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
        mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
    }
    toggleFab();

    drawer.closeDrawers();
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            return homeFragment;
        case 1:
            ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
            return profileFragment;
        case 2:
            RateusFragment rateusFragment = new RateusFragment();
            return rateusFragment;
        case 3:
            ScoreFragment scoreFragment = new ScoreFragment();
            return scoreFragment;
        case 4:
            NotificationsFragment notificationsFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
            return notificationsFragment;
        case 5:
            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            return settingsFragment;
        default:
            return new HomeFragment();
    }
}

private void setToolBarTitle() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
}

private void selectNavMenu() {
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setCheckable(true);
}

private void setUpNavigationView() {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_profile:
                    navItemIndex = 1;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PROFILE;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_rateus:
                    navItemIndex = 2;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_RATEUS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_score:
                    navItemIndex = 3;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SCORE;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_notifications:
                    navItemIndex = 4;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_NOTIFICATIONS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    navItemIndex = 5;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SETTINGS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_about_us:
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_terms:
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TermsActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                default:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
            }
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            menuItem.setChecked(true);

            return true;
        }
    });

    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            //when nav closed this will triggered - leaving blank so nothing won't happen
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            //when nav opened this will triggered - leaving blank so nothing won't happen
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };
    drawer.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        return;
    }
    if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {
        if (navItemIndex != 0) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadHomeFragment();
            return;
        }
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (navItemIndex == 0) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }
    if (navItemIndex == 4) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notifications, menu);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_mark_all_read) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All marked as read!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_clear_notifications) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All Cleared!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void toggleFab() {
    if (navItemIndex == 0)
        fab.show();
    else
        fab.hide();
}
```

}

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of problems with the code:

Make sure u add break in switch:

```
case R.id.nav_about_us:
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class));
    drawer.closeDrawers();
    break;  //add break
case R.id.nav_terms:
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TermsActivity.class));
    drawer.closeDrawers();
    break;  
default:
    navItemIndex = 0;
     break;
```

Also your fragment not loading as you are not calling the function properly:

in your Switch case:

```
case R.id.nav_home:
    navItemIndex = 0;
    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
    Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();  //get fragment based on index
    ReplaceFragment(fragment);  //now replace them and load new one
    drawer.closeDrawers();
    break;
```

in `ReplaceFragment` method write:

```
public void ReplaceFragment(Fragment r_fragment) {
    if (r_fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, r_fragment).commit();

    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
    }

}
```

Also overWrite following methods:

```
 @Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
    drawerView.bringToFront();  //add this two lines
    drawerView.requestLayout();
}

 @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
```

Comment: Well, I added the function inside the Switch case - it replaces the fragments but only when I press twice.

Comment: in your `onOptionsItemSelected` method comment out `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` and add `return  false;`

Comment: Hi,
Still need to click twice in each item in NavigationDrawer for the fragments to change.

Here's the changes in onOptionsItemSelected:

//        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        return false;

Comment: @user3181843 check the edit also for full implementation see https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your time but your answer doesn't change anything in the problem.
You got me to a way I need to press twice on item to trigger the Fragment change (which is good, 'cuase it means the code probably doesn't deliver the right TAG when needed or something) but yet, any of the changes doesn't lead to 1 click on item to switch Fragments.
Thank you again.

Comment: first: `answer doesn't change anything in the problem.`  that's not true .. i found out some problems with the code and provide solution..that works well right!!. There are some methods u need to overwrite and also there is   unnecessary condition...it will work on first click also.

Comment: Got you mate,
Still the first problem was the fragment change in the same frame - that problem is still here after the code changes that you suggested.
I'm not saying you're not doing good - that's just not the right answer mate.

Comment: i get it completely...debug the code put a log inside each item to see wheather it  calls `ReplaceFragment` thankx

Comment: what was the problem?